# Notepad++. I want to delete everything after first ".jpeg" in notepad++.

Tags: notepad++, notepad

This is only one line, I have thousand in a file
http://img6a.flixcart.com//image/mobile/z/r/j/micromax-bling-q55-bling-limited-iifa-edition-400x400-imadfebcbg7yzrmh.jpeg,http://img5a.flixcart.com//image/mobile/z/r/j/micromax-bling-q55-bling-limited-iifa-edition-75x75-imadfebcbg7yzrmh.jpeg

Comment: I get a 404 on your image. Have you tried macros? Your question is very vague. ——— actually, I see what you're getting at. Use a macro.

Comment: How the frak does this nonsense get upvotes? I do not get it. Some of you people just upvote for fun I swear

Answer (score 3):

Input:

```
http://img6a.flixcart.com//image/mobile/z/r/j/micromax-bling-q55-bling-limited-iifa-edition-400x400-imadfebcbg7yzrmh.jpeg,http://img5a.flixcart.com//image/mobile/z/r/j/micromax-bling-q55-bling-limited-iifa-edition-75x75-imadfebcbg7yzrmh.jpeg
```

Find and replace in regex mode:
Find what: `^(.*?jpeg).*$`
Replace with: `\1`

[image]

Result:

```
http://img6a.flixcart.com//image/mobile/z/r/j/micromax-bling-q55-bling-limited-iifa-edition-400x400-imadfebcbg7yzrmh.jpeg
```

Explanation:

```
^            Start of string
(.*?jpeg)    Everything until first jpeg, stored in group \1
.*           followed by any number of characters
$            end of line
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I would do, using a [macro](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Macros):

You have a thousand lines of the form

```
http://www.alice.com/bob.jpeg;http://www.wolf.com/rabbit.jpeg
```

which you would like to turn into

```
http://www.alice.com/bob.jpeg
```

by deleting everything after the first instance of ".jpeg".

- Back the file up.
- Open the file in Notepad++ (obviously).
- Go to the `Macro -> Start recording` menu item.
- Go to the `Find` dialog by pressing <kbd>Ctrl+f</kbd>.
- Make sure that the settings are:

  - *Match whole word only:* unchecked;
  - *Match Case:* unchecked;
  - *Wrap Around:* unchecked;
  - *Search Mode:* 'Normal';
  - *Direction:* Down.
- Enter ".jpeg" and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This will select the next instance of `.jpeg` after the cursor.
- Press <kbd>Escape</kbd>. This will dismiss the "Find" window.
- Press <kbd>Right</kbd>. This will clear the selection and move the cursor to *after* the `.jpeg`.
- Press <kbd>Shift+End</kbd>. This will select the rest of the line **after** the `.jpeg`.
- Press <kbd>Delete</kbd> to delete the selection.
- Press <kbd>Right</kbd> to move the cursor to the start of the next line.
- Go to the `Macro -> Stop recording` menu item.

At this point, the macro is set up and <s>should</s> will be ready to use.

Go to the `Macro -> Playback` menu item to test it on the next line.

If that works as you expect, try the `Macro -> Run a macro multiple times` menu item and try to run it a few times (be cautious to start with, say, five times).

If, at this point, the result is as you expect, you're good to go! Enter a larger number in the `Run a macro multiple times` menu item to get close to the end of the file, then use the `Playback` item (or press <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+P</kbd>) to do the last few ones.